# how to detect object type and tag

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to Windows Phone 7.
I clicked one button and got:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Is it possible get the tag property and object type of sender?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) by using the [GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method:

```
sender.GetType();
```

If you want to cast it as a button, you can do this.

```
var myButton = sender as Button;
if(myButton != null)
    var buttonTag = myButton.Tag;
```

Using `as` instead of `(Button)sender` means that instead of an exception being thrown if it can't be cast as a Button, it will simply return null. We can then check if it's null and, if it's not null, we can access its Tag property.